# HTTP 400 : detected invalid characters in the URL. IIS decoding URL too early? Whats going on here?

Tags: .net, http, url, iis-7

So i have this URL: 
http://test.com/afolder/who-else-wants-to-make-horror-movies%3f/

which is URL encoded version of :
http://test.com/afolder/who-else-wants-to-make-horror-movies?/

But IIS7 throws a 400:

> HTTP Error 400.0 - Bad Request ASP.NET
>   detected invalid characters in the
>   URL.

But why is it doing that if i have correctly encoded the URL?

I'm also having the same issue with other URL encoded chars like '/' which is '%2f' but when .net resolves the handler it does so after decoding the URL which then changes the effective path, grrrr.

Comment: Is it possible not to use those characters in the URL?

Comment: heh, denial is better than cure? I guess i could strip them, but i was hoping to figure it out too.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Looks like there are some issues with IIS7 on x64....not sure if this is your issue or not:

http://blogs.iis.net/rakkimk/archive/2008/10/10/asp-net-2-0-x64-you-may-get-http-400-bad-request-or-error-as-mentioned-in-kb-932552-or-826437.aspx

Comment: I am infact running iis7 on x64, but i'm running .net 3.5 sp1 which is newer than those hotfixes

Comment: And you have tried setting the VerificationCompatibility registry value to 1 as mentioned there? As a sidenote, stackoverflow.com has a similar response when you include %3f in a url.

Comment: yes, it looks like stackoverflow doesn't like a %3f in a url, but isn't phased by a ? within the url

Comment: required rebooting the server after making the registry update, then worked.