# How to upload files over 2Gb to IIS 7.5 / .Net 4?

Tags: .net, asp.net, iis, upload

As far as I know IIS and ASP.NET has a limitation of 2Gb files upload. Are there any solutions for this in IIS 7.5 and .Net 4?

Comment: You want to upload files that are 2+ GB via HTTP?!  You're aware that uploads are capped around 128K on residential broadband, depending on the ISP...

Comment: 128K??? What ISP are you using? Even most dial-up providers allow uploads larger than that (or are you referring to speed?).

Comment: In general there is a max bandwidth cap. Here is a recent [example](http://consumerist.com/2011/07/man-exceeds-bandwidth-cap-comcast-denies-him-internet-for-a-year.html). However, I believe @OMG refers to max upload speed. Anyway, that shouldn't concern us because we don't know the exact case of user695797's application. She/He may use it on her/his lan or in a way that upload speed isn't a problem.

Comment: Hey OMG, its for corporate intranet.

Answer (score 2):

I found a [blog post](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/friis/archive/2013/06/19/uploading-large-file-to-iis-7-5-or-8-using-file-input-element.aspx) that explains the cryptic error "ASP.NET detected invalid characters in the URL."

From the blog post:

> When the integrated pipeline is used, we go though webengine code
>   (webengine4!MgdGetRequestBasics) which doesn't support more than 2 GB
>   content-length and  a System.ArithmeticException exception is raised
>   which subsequently cause the HTTP 400 error. With the classic
>   pipeline, we don't use webengine4 but the old ASPNET_ISAPI model and
>   we don't hit the above issue.

The post also describes how the author was able to upload files larger than 2 gigs.

Comment: Looks looks that post just says that upload over 2Gb is not possible, useless.

Comment: It doesn't say anywhere in the blog post that it's impossible to upload over 2Gb.

Answer (score 1):

Have a look [here](http://forums.aurigma.com/yaf_postst3654_HOWTO-Configuring-IIS7.aspx).

You have to add to your application's web.config the following code:

```
<system.webServer>
<security>
    <requestFiltering>
        <requestLimits maxAllowedContentLength ="2147482624" /><!--this value in bytes~2GB-->
    </requestFiltering>
</security>
<system.webServer>
```

Also in web.config find the *system.web* section and the *httpRuntime key* and
modify the *maxRequestLength* and *executionTimeout* attributes of this key as mentioned in the reference I gave you.

I hope this works for you.

Comment: Really the maxAllowedContentLength can be set to 4294967295, that is over 4Gb. However the upload of files over 2Gb fails anyway. The server responds HTTP Error 400.0 - Bad Request "ASP.NET detected invalid characters in the URL." I am sure there are no any bad characters. Any ideas?

Comment: I am not sure why this is happening and I am unable right now to check it but take a look [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/811763/http-400-detected-invalid-characters-in-the-url-iis-decoding-url-too-early-wh). It seems to be your case. Check it and inform us if it worked for you.

Comment: No Master_ex, it did not help. Any idea how to upload 10Gb file to IIS over HTTP? Breaking file into pieces is not an option.

Comment: I just wonder if users voting for this answer has aver tried to use the recommended solution. I bet never tried to upload 5Gb file...

Comment: Hey user695797, take a look [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1599409/upload-large-files1gb-asp-net). You can read the bytes of the file on the client and send it to the server. You can do it yourself or use something like [NeatUpload](http://neatupload.codeplex.com/)

Comment: So, Master_ex, did you try to upload files over 2Gb using your solution? Using that NeatUpload or any other client software?

Comment: Hi again, I hadn't tested it until now and it seems that you are right. After googling it it seems that the 2GB limit is a limitation of asp .net. I have also tried NeatUpload without any luck. The only idea that I have right now to accomplish that is to split the file into chunks smaller than 2GB and merge them again in the server side.