# Unable to upload 4GB file using jquery

Tags: java, javascript, jquery, file-upload, swfupload

I am trying to upload a 4.8 GB file using jQuery transmit plugin and SWFUpload. I am able to upload a file size 2.5 GB.

Is there any system restriction on file upload?

I am using a 64-bit system.

Comment: Its more than likely going to be a server restriction.  Are you aware of what it is or if there are any?

Comment: Maybe the server's file system doesn't support files over 4GB. It would be true if it's FAT32, or if the code the handles the upload in the server doesn't support 64-bit file offsets.

Comment: Can you describe what goes wrong in a bit more detail?
This is almost certainly not a client-side (i.e. jQuery or swfupload) problem. Check your server logs (or event viewer if you're using IIS) and look at the error returned by the server.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It could also be a limitation in `php.ini`.

> "*Clarification on the MAX_FILE_SIZE hidden form field: PHP has the
> somewhat strange feature of checking multiple "maximum file sizes".
> The two widely known limits are the php.ini settings "post_max_size"
> and "upload_max_size", which in combination impose a hard limit on the
> maximum amount of data that can be received.*"
>
> -svenr

Whole post:
https://www.php.net/manual/en/features.file-upload.php#74692

Answer (score 0):

Are you using ASP.NET with IIS as the web server? If so then you will need to do some configuring here. Check out this SO question: [How to upload files over 2Gb to IIS 7.5 / .Net 4?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6802519/how-to-upload-files-over-2gb-to-iis-7-5-net-4)

It shows how to configure the web.config of your site to allow large uploads. If that fails to work, then you might need to configure IIS itself to allow large uploads. I'm not sure how to do this yet, I will do research if required, but try the web.config method first.

Some more useful links:

http://www.webdavsystem.com/server/documentation/upload
http://www.telerik.com/help/aspnet-ajax/upload-uploading-large-files.html