# Forms login redirect fails when original URL has a query string

Tags: asp.net, forms-authentication

We're using forms authentication in an ASP.Net 3.5 web application under IIS 7.5. We've discovered that when the source page has a query string like this:

```
http://server/dir/page.aspx?func=add
```

The redirect from the login page looks sends me to:

```
http://server/dir/page.aspx%3ffunc%3dadd
```

Even though that URL decodes to `http://server/dir/page.aspx?func=add` IIS complains with

```
HTTP Error 400.0 - Bad Request
ASP.NET detected invalid characters in the URL.
```

My Google-fu has failed me on researching this behavior. Does anyone have a solution or a pointer to more information?

**Updates:**

Answers to questions:

<strike>Yes, we are calling FormsAuthentication.RedirectFromLoginPage.</strike>

I looked at [this article](https://stackoverflow.com/q/811763/303298) and that appears to be for IIs7 and Win28. When looking at the referenced patched files, my dates were more currect by roughly 3 years. Though I did add the referenced reg-key and rebooted the box; still happens.

Comment: Are you calling `FormsAuthentication.RedirectFromLoginPage`? Also, in the web.config's `authentication/forms` do you have the protection attribute set? [see here for modes](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/1d3t3c61.aspx)

Comment: It may be useful: http://stackoverflow.com/q/811763/303298

Comment: Yes, Jim, we do call `FormsAuthentication.RedirectFromLoginPage(response.Token.UserName, true);` No protection is not set, that seems to be about the cookie protection rather than the return URL.

Comment: That isn't working, vladimir.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After digging in because I wasn't finding answers and it had annoyed me enough to step through the code I found the answer.

As it turns out, I was wrong. Where we are calling `FormsAuthentication.RedirectFromLoginPage` is dead code and the redirect is handled on the client side after the authentication service tells us the attempt was successful.

It was this chunk of code that was failing:

```
var queryStringParts = window.location.search.split('=');
var targetPath = queryStringParts[1];
targetPath = targetPath.replace(/(%2f)/g,'/'); // <-- Here's where we weren't doing enough
```

I've since written a utility method to get the query string value and handle it correctly.

```
function getQueryStringValue(name, defaultValue) {
    var value = defaultValue;
    var queryString = window.location.search;
    var startPos = queryString.indexOf(name);

    if (startPos > -1) {
        startPos += name.length + 1
        var endPos = queryString.indexOf('&', startPos);
        if (endPos == -1) {
            // Incase there is no ampersand (&) after the query string value 
            // we're after we go to the last index + 1
            endPos = queryString.length;
        }
        value = unescape(queryString.substring(startPos, endPos));
    }
    return value;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try adding the following into your web.config:

```
<system.web>
   <httpRuntime 
        requestValidationMode="2.0"
        requestPathInvalidCharacters="&lt;,&gt;,*,%,:,&amp;,\"
        relaxedUrlToFileSystemMapping="true"
    />       
</system.web>

<system.webServer>
    <security>
        <requestFiltering allowDoubleEscaping="true" />
    </security>
</system.webServer>
```

Comment: Using those httpRuntime values causes a configuration exception. Keeping the security values does not fix the problem.